# Efficient streaming with Firebase Realtime

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

My server is getting chunks of a big text, and I want to display the text right away on the client before receiving the last chunk.

Currently, every time I receive a chunk I append it to the string I had and set this longer string on my Firebase realtime.

something like this:

```py
complete_response = ''
for chunk in response:
   complete_response += chunk
   ref.set(complete_response)
```

This does not seem super efficient to me, because every time I receive a chunk I send to the client that chunk along with all the previous chunks concatenated together.

I was wondering if it was more efficient to use the push() method? But I don't know if when I create a new node the client will re-fetch all the previous nodes too or be smart about it.

```py
complete_response = ''
for chunk in response:
   ref.push().set(chunk)
```

My client is a `Flutter` app where I am using StreamBuilder to listen to updates to the Firebase Realtime db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending the full string when you only appended a smaller subset to it is indeed not the most efficient.

A common alternative would indeed be to keep a list of the chunks, and push each new chunk to the end of that list. The clients who read the data would then have to read the full list, and reconstitute the full string from the chunks.

Comment: Thank you.

Just to be clear when you say a list you mean the method I suggested with the push?

This blog post says we shouldn't use arrays on Firebase realtime: https://firebase.blog/posts/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase

Comment: Yup, that's a list as in https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data - created by calling `push()` in Flutter.